# My Bootstrap is currently overriding my custom CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

My app requires Bootstrap. However, it is overriding my custom CSS then the navbar that I have set is now displayed in a weird manner. What am I doing wrong and what can do to fix it? My end goal is to let the bootstrap work along side with the css.

Here is the image for more clarification:

[image]

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Client Server Application Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="faq.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!--BootStrap CSS-->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">Revolutionary Fitness</div>
      <ul>
        <div class="items">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="service.html">Our Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="training.html">Gyms Training</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gym Location</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="login.php">Login</a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <li class="search-icon">
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <label class="icon">
            <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Accordion Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Accordion Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Accordion Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>

      <ul class="list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="faq.html">FAQs</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="copyright">
        <small>&copy;2022 Singapore Polytehnic</small>
      </p>
    </footer>

  
    
    <!--BootStrap JavaScript-->
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
    background: #1b1b1b;
}
nav:after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
nav .logo{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #1b1b1b;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 8px 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    color: cyan;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #33ffff,
                0 0 5px #66ffff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: cyan;
    box-shadow: none;
}
nav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: top .3s;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
    top: 70px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
nav ul ul li{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
nav ul ul li a{
    line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul .search-icon{
    height: 40px;
    width: 240px;
    display: flex;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
nav ul .search-icon input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
nav ul .search-icon .icon{
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul .search-icon .icon:hover{
    background: #e6e6e6;
}
nav ul .search-icon .icon span{
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 18px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:968px){
    nav .logo{
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul div.items{
        flex: 3;
    }
    nav ul .search-icon{
        display: none;
    }
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: crimson;
    color:white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.container{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
.footer{
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}
.footer .social{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    color:#4b4c4d;
}
.footer .social a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.footer .social a:hover{
    color:#24262b;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.footer ul{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer ul li a{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
.footer ul li a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
.footer .copyright{
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:black;
}
```

Much help is appreciated!

Comment: You could use `!important` in your css classes

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Bootstrap link is not working properly.

actually, Bootstrap purpose is reducing css No of line codes.

simply, You can follow my steps..

Try to use this Link:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Finally, you can search on bootstrap, what you want to use.

`https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/`

If you want to use Navbar? simply copy and paste your project..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```